# TypeError: http.IncomingMessage is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-5

Recently, I changed webpack config in my VueJS's App/Website,
*vue.config.js:*

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
          "fs": false,
          "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
          "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
          "http": require.resolve("https-browserify"), // < Important
          "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
          "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
          "net": require.resolve("net-browserify")
      },
    }
  },
});
```

After using `"http": require.resolve("https-browserify")` I get `Uncaught TypeError: http.IncomingMessage is undefined @request.js:31`,
sometimes its `http.serverresponse is undefined`
How can i Fix this?
Is this Related to Express or Webpack5?

Answer (score 1):

Core `https` module does not have the `IncomingMessage` member, while `http` [does](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage).

Likely you want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-browserify instead.

Comment: where do i map it? in vue.config.js?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-browserify#protip

Comment: Try replacing `https-browserify` with `http-browserify`